# nginx 502 bad gateway after ubuntu server restart

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, fastcgi

I have a situation with an ubuntu server that is configured to run with nginx and fastcgi. The problem is that after a restart any request is giving 502 bad gateway in browser.

In error log the error looks like this:

```
 connect() to unix:/var/run/fastcgi.socket-4 failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream
```

after I create the file manually (i do not know if this is correct) the error is changing to:

```
connect() to unix:/var/run/fastcgi.socket-4 failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream
```

nginx server has configuration settings for each website like this:

```
 location ~ \.php$ {
                        fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/fastcgi.socket-4;
                        fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE       CGI/1.1;
                        fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE         nginx;
                        fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
                        fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
                        fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE            $content_type;
                        fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH          $content_length;
                        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         /document_root/$fastcgi_scr
                        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME             $fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI             $request_uri;
                        fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI            $document_uri;
                        fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT           /document_root;
                        fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL         $server_protocol;
                        fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR             $remote_addr;
                        fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT             $remote_port;
                        fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR             $server_addr;
                        fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT             $server_port;
                        fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME             $server_name;
                        fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS         200;
                        fastcgi_index                   index.php;
                        fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
                        }
```

Note that I am quite new to nginx, however I have experience and knowhow in apache and php.

Comment: The php service is probably not running, im not sure what it's called but i think `sudo service php5-fcgi start` might make it work

Comment: problem is that fastcgi is not working under this service. running what you say: php5-fcgi: unrecognized service

Comment: like I say i don't really know it's name, I use `php5-fpm` my self, you could try `sudo service --status-all | grep php` to know what's the right name

Comment: found it. it was spawn-fcgi and I started it using  /etc/init.d/spawn-fcgi start and it worked. thank you very much as your advice did the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `502 bad gateway` error means that the backend server (which is php in your case) is not functioning properly, and since it was related to a server restart, I guessed it would be related to it not starting on boot time.

Since I didn't know the service name, running `sudo service --status-all` lists all services on the system.

After finding the php service name which turned to be `spawn-fcgi` in your case, you can start it using

```
sudo service spawn-fcgi start
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/spawn-fcgi start
```

You need to make sure that it auto starts on boot, to find that you can easily google how to make a service start on boot, it's very simple

Comment: It worked! In my case I saw a minus signal at nginx then I ran `service nginx start` but I ran `/etc/init.d/nginx start` before it and didn't work. There is some difference between those two commands? `service nginx start` and `/etc/init.d/nginx start`

Comment: I'm not really sure what's the exact difference, but it's preferred to use your service manager,`service`, `systemctl`, or what ever your OS uses.