# How to run the gunicorn bind command in background in Jenkins?

Tags: nginx, jenkins, gunicorn, devops

I am using gunicorn app.wsgi:application --bind=0.0.0.0:1312 --daemon to run a Django application in backgound .It is working on the ubuntu terminal But its not working in jenkins .Its giving 502 nginx error.
nginx error.log:

```
(111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 106.51.133.80, s
$.80, server: 0.0.0.0:1312, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:1312/", host: "0.0.0.0:81"
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I am glad it helped.

Comment: Also, if the below answer helped, request you to upvote and provide the bounty :)

Comment: @dildeepak did some extra changes also in /etc/sudoers file . I gave superuser access to jenkins to run a script ,after that it working .Thanks for your answer it helped .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***502 bad gateway error*** means that the back-end server is not functioning properly, and since it was related to Jenkins browser there could be some of the reasons:

1. **It would be related to not starting on boot time**

Or

2. **Bad buffering/timeout configuration etc**

**For 1st case** : running `sudo service --status-all` lists all services on the system.

After finding the service name, you can start it using

```
sudo service spawn-fcgi start
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/spawn-fcgi start
```

You need to make sure that it auto starts on boot, to find that you can easily google how to make a service start on boot, it's very simple.

**For 2nd case:** You can try increasing the buffer as well as timeout times.

```
http {
...
fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
...
}
```

For more details, please refer the below links:

- https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/502-bad-gateway-error-using-nginx/
- http://developernote.com/2012/09/how-i-fixed-nginx-502-bad-gateway-error/
- [nginx 502 bad gateway after ubuntu server restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375570/nginx-502-bad-gateway-after-ubuntu-server-restart)